# Connecting through PHP to an SQL Server, using the Windows account

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, windows-authentication

I am trying to connect using PHP to an SQL Server on another machine. I have found two ways of doing this. Either with odbc_connect or sqlsrvr connect.

```
    $connection = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=$serverName;Database=$db;", 'user', 'pass');
```

or

```
  $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, array('UID' => '', 'PWD' => ''));
```

The connection works if I try to connect to an SQL account. Unfortunately I cannot manage to connect using the Windows Authentication.

So far I have tried the following : used a working pass, added Trusted_Connection=yes; or Integrated Security=SSPI; . I have also tried combining this with fastcgi.impersonate = 1 or 0.

When I use directly my user and pass I get a login denied error and when I try the windows authentication with sspi I receive the following error:Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

I've googled the problem a lot but I could not find a solution. Some people however were talking about php not using the Network Service account and that that might be the problem.

Does anyone know how I could fix this or maybe give me a lead?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You'd be logging in with the UID that your php process (or webserver process) is running under.

Comment: Is there any way to change the user that the process is runing under? I haven't done this before and I would appreciate a "for dummies" type of link. I always thought that apps run while I'm logged in are run with my account.

Comment: depends on your webserver, but there are a lot of things to consider when changing the operation UID - you can totally break the web server unless you do it right.

Comment: Do you have by any chance a link or perhaps something that I can google?

Comment: I have finally fixed the problem by installing IIS6 and php. The I configured inetmgr in order to change the user that was being used by default for the anonymous logon. For anyone else having this issue here is the link : http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/247/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis-60/

Answer (score 3):

I was able to establish a trusted connection to a remote SQL server from PHP running on a seperate IIS server using:

```
$connectionInfo = array('Database' => $dbname);
$con = sqlsrv_connect($servername,$connectionInfo);
```

In php.ini:

```
fastcgi.impersonate = 0
mssql.secure_connection = On
```

In IIS for my PHP site:

```
Anonymous Authentication = Disabled
Windows Authentication = Enabled
Application Pool settings for site: Integrated, Network Service
```

Database Security on SQL Server for $dbname database:

```
create login: domainname\iisservername$  
map domainname\iisservername$ to db_datareader privilege for $dbname database
```

Note: The $ in the iisservername is important.  With the above settings IIS will establish a trusted connection with the SQL server without the need to store userid and password information in your PHP file.  Locally the permissions used by the application pool are "Network Service".   Remotely, these permissions pass through the network as user domainname\iisservername$.

Comment: how to connect with appache server

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the IIS Console
2. Configure your App Pool identity with the desired user which must have enough permissions in your SQL Server+Database
3. Select your "Specific Website"
4. Open "Authentication" settings
5. Right-click on "Anonymous Authentication" and click on "Edit"
6. By last select the option: Application pool identity (radio button) and press the "OK" button to apply the changes.

Comment: This is how my IIS is configured, and it is working against a particular instance of SQL Server. However on that SQL Server instance I cannot see the Application Pool's identity as an entry in the SQL Server's Logins folder. When I update my PHP application's connection string to connect to a different server, I receive the error `[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user '{domain}\{username}'`. Without seeing that account in the working SQL Server's Login folder, I am not sure how to get this connection working to a different SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

basically the problem is that the identity that is used to connect to the server will always be the identity of the process in which PHP is running

[This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/02/10/sql-server-driver-for-php-understanding-windows-authentication.aspx) link may help you.

Comment: Hi. I have already went throught that post. Unfortunately the solutions he proposes does not work for me. The impersonate setting has no effect and the user always stays the same when trying to connect with the windows authentication.

Answer (score 1):

For PHP on IIS 7.5 to connect without a username and password using SSPI authentication. I had to do the following:

In my IIS application pool advanced settings, I set it to use a custom account Domain\username to the user I needed PHP to connect as.

In my IIS specific website, I changed the Basic settings to Connect As that same Domain\username.

In my PHP code I could then connect using `$conn = sqlsrv_connect($dbhost, array("Database" => $dbname, "UID" => "", "PWD" => ""));`

Other notes: `fastcgi.impersonate = 1`
And I only have: Anonymous Authentication Enabled
[*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/02/10/sql-server-driver-for-php-understanding-windows-authentication.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName);`

The array is optional. Windows authentication is used as default. See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296161.aspx)

IIS should have Windows authentication enabled and anonymous access turned off.

Comment: Yes. Same error : Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

Comment: If so anonymous access would be set to false and Windows authentication set to true.

Comment: The web server is actually my laptop for the moment. IIS not configured. I have not used it yet, but I will try to install it and see what happens. Thanks !

Comment: Yes. This [link](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5f8fe119-4095-4094-bba5-7dec361c7afe.mspx?mfr=true) should help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the IIS Console
2. Go to your site
3. Open "Authentication" settings
   Right-click on "Anonymous Authentication" and click on "Edit"
   By last select the option: Application pool identity (radio button) and press the "OK" button to apply the changes.
4. Go to "Application Pools" and get the application pool name.
5. Open SSMS (SQL management studio), enter the relevant database and choose "Security".
6. Add a new user, fill only the name and save. The name of the user should be: 
   IIS APPPOOL\{YOUR_APP_POOL_NAME}

Good luck!